# Take screenshot at specified resolution

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking into possibly creating an app that will allow me to take a screenshot of a particular window (in this case the browser) at a specified resolution.

I don't really want to actually change my monitors resolution. What I'd like to do is to be able to get a screenshot as it would appear at 800x600, 1024x768 etc etc.

I know how to take a screenshot using .net / c# but I'm wondering if there's a way to "trick" it into taking one at a different resolution (there probably isn't but I thought I'd ask anyway, so excuse the potentially stupid question).

Cheers

Comment: Just resize the window in question to 800x600 and capture only that window. The resulting image will then be in 800x600.

Comment: I assume there is a way to do this programatically? Is it in the .NET framework or will I be delving into the winapi?

Answer (score 1):

take a screenshot and save the original image at a desired resolution.

here's code snippet to demonstrate the idea:

```
Bitmap bmp_with_actual_resolution = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp_with_actual_resolution);
g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
Bitmap bmp_800_600 = new Bitmap(800, 600);
Graphics g_800_600 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp_800_600);
g_800_600.DrawImage(bmp_with_actual_resolution, 0, 0, 800, 600);
bmp_800_600.Save("D:\\file_800_600.jpg", ImageFormat.Bmp);
Bitmap bmp_1024_768 = new Bitmap(1024, 768);
Graphics g_1024_768 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp_1024_768);
g_1024_768.DrawImage(bmp_with_actual_resolution, 0, 0, 1024, 768);
bmp_1024_768.Save("D:\\file_1024_768.jpg", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: @Eranga maybe... so what? it was just to demonstrate the idea

Answer (score 0):

Well if you mean make a screenshot of how the everything would look when the resolution will be 800x600. You cannot do that. Because Windows will make everything bigger, relocate icons etc.

If you mean resizing a screenshot to another resolution this is fairly simple and available easily in C#.

Comment: I mean the first thing you mention. As it would look at 800x600. I'm interested in knowing if the layout of a specific page breaks visually at any resolution is all.

Answer (score 0):

Looking on your comment: " I'm interested in knowing if the layout of a specific page breaks visually at any resolution is all", making just screen shot is wrong way to go. Probbaly on your porgram, I just deduct from post, you have dynamic layout that you would like to test against different resolutions to see UX among them.

1. I don't think, it's good solution to make in automation, just try it manually as a lot of stuff just by looking on image can not be figured out.
2. If you by the way want to do that:

   Here is a sample how to change screen resolution from code: [Screen resolution change from C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Joshy_geo/changescreenresolution10102006112110AM/changescreenresolution.aspx)

And here is the code how to get screen shot from the screen, based on coordinates. So with small trick you will be able to make it on active window too:

[Capturing Screen in C#](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial181_Capturing-screenshots-using-Csharp.html)

In other words, if I undesrtand really what you want, first change resolution of screen, after make a snapshot.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't need to go into a detailed check of the site at each resolution, just a quick glance as the detailed checks will be done later. So for now a screenshot is all I need to give me a quick overview. My main interest is just to judge the amount of whitespace there will be at each resolution rather than check for any html nuances that occur. Cheers